# How to reference resources created by for_each in Terraform

Tags: terraform

I have created multiple subnets [private/public] by using `for_each` in Terraform as below

```
resource "aws_subnet" "public" {
  for_each = toset(data.aws_availability_zones.azs.names)
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.vpc.id
  cidr_block = cidrsubnet(var.private_ranges,1 ,index(data.aws_availability_zones.azs.names, each.value))
  availability_zone = each.value
  map_public_ip_on_launch = true
  tags = merge(local.common_tags, map("Name", join("-", [local.prefix, index(data.aws_availability_zones.azs.names,each.value )]),
  "Availibility Zone", each.value, "Type", "Public"))

  lifecycle {
    prevent_destroy = false
  }
}

resource "aws_subnet" "private" {
  for_each = toset(data.aws_availability_zones.azs.names)
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.vpc.id
  cidr_block = cidrsubnet(var.private_ranges,1 ,index(data.aws_availability_zones.azs.names, each.value))
  availability_zone = each.value
  tags = merge(local.common_tags, map("Name", join("-", [local.prefix, index(data.aws_availability_zones.azs.names,each.value )]),
  "Availibility Zone", each.value, "Type", "Private"))

  lifecycle {
    prevent_destroy = false
  }
}
```

I need to reference these subnets in other resource `aws_default_network_acl`

```
resource "aws_default_network_acl" "default" {
  default_network_acl_id = aws_vpc.vpc.default_network_acl_id
  subnet_ids = <can you tell me how to reference the subnet ids here>
........
```

Comment: Do you want all of them? Or a specific subset of them?

Comment: all, private and public

Comment: i tried the following approach and seems its working ```subnet_ids = concat([for subnet in aws_subnet.private: subnet.id], [for subnet in aws_subnet.public: subnet.id])```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I did it using the following solution,

```
subnet_ids = concat([for subnet in aws_subnet.private: subnet.id], [for subnet in aws_subnet.public: subnet.id])
```